# How to reduce number of variables for path analyses/SEM?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, variable

I'm planning to create a path analysis or SEM model to look at what environmental factors affect how a species is distributed in space. I'm interested in looking at climate, landcover, and a few other predictors, and am interested to see how much of the non-climate effects could be considered an indirect effect of climate.

I have a climate dataset containing 19 bioclimatic variables (https://www.worldclim.org/data/bioclim.html) - Annual Mean Temperature, Max Temperature of Warmest Month, Mean Temperature of Wettest Quarter, Precipitation Seasonality etc. I also have a landcover dataset that will allow me to calculate for a given area the % wetland, % barren etc for 12 variables.

I need to narrow down which variables are most relevant to make the path model feasible. I was thinking of grouping highly correlated variables and keeping one from each group. Then I was imagining testing each chosen predictor in a model by itself to see how well it predicts species distribution, and only putting the ones that are good predictors into the model. My logic was that the predictors meeting this criteria could be directly or indirectly influencing species distribution, and I will eliminate the predictors that will never be strong predictors.

But this doesn't make sense does it? Is it possible that Variable 1 could be insignificant by itself and significant when including variable 2?

What would be a better way to narrow these predictors down to a reasonable number to put in a path model?

Comment: There isn't really a limit on the number of variables you can include (and if there is, it's much higher than 19).

Comment: Really? I thought there was. I can imagine perhaps there wouldn't be a technical limitations, but I was under the impression that with more than 6-10 it would get too confusing to interpret

Comment: Interpretability depends on the model. I've fit models with 50 or more variables.

Comment: Here's a paper with models with 23 variables: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2871669/